# Nested conditional if and else if commands

Tags: php, if-statement

I am modifying an existing PHP / HTML live site to add some new conditional statements based on some new age verification criteria.

The page now loads, but my old form is not posting anymore after adding these new conditions.

Basically, I've inserted 3 new conditions in an if/else if/else if structure, surrounding existing page, which redirects based on these checks.

Previously there was only one set of page redirects and the code worked perfectly. Now it works with some conditions but not others.

```
/** Old (Working) Code: **/
if ($var > 0) { //existing working conditions
    // Some code
    if ($var2 > 0) { //existing working conditions
        // end old stuff that works)

        /** New (broken) code: **/
        if (($type == 'R') && ($age > '17')) { /// Type R AND 18 or older

            if ($adult == "0") {
                header('location: adult.php?test=' . $id . '');
            } else if ($a_values == "0") {
                header('location: a_values.php?test=' . $id . '');
            }
            //(many more pages to check)

        } else if (($type == '') && ($age > '17')) { /// No Type AND 18 or older

            if ($adult == "0") {
                header('location: adult.php?test=' . $id . '');
            } else if ($a_values == "0") {
                header('location: a_values.php?test=' . $id . '');
            }
            // (many more pages to check)

        } else if (($type == 'C') && ($age < '18')) { // else Type C OR not 18 yo

            if ($not_adult == "0") {
                header('location: not_adult.php?test=' . $id . '');
            } else if ($not_adult_values == "0") {
                header('location: not_adult_values.php?test=' . $id . '');
            }
            // (many more pages to check)

        } else {  // end ((new stuff)) and execute the rest of page if none of the if/else conditions and redirects are met


        }
        // ((old stuff that works))
    } // end $var2
} // end $var
```

I don't want to use a different coding methodology,  I just want to figure out the correct logic / syntax so that the page works like it used to and the form below processes correctly.

Comment: I inserted test code to see if each section correctly captures the variables...  echo 'Bottom assmt_type:'.$assmt_type.' age '.$age; ... It works if assmt_type is C but doesn't display if its R on page reloads when I change the variable in the Database

Comment: I did have to separate each top level IF condition to be stand alone, with if/elseif inside of it, without a connected else if, for the form to process below.  I also removed the quotes from the number because I think it was processing it as text, within the conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's the case, but if you have HTML code before any header(), that's probably why your code doesn't work.

Comment: All the html code is under the header.  The page works perfectly and the form posts, until I added this new conditional logic in the php section

Comment: Could it be the typo? You have `else if ($not_adultt_values == "0")` in one condition. With double t

Comment: No... no typo... ill fix that error now (thats fake for this post)

Comment: What do you mean by "my old form is not posting anymore"? Does it give you any specific error?

Comment: It displays, takes the drop down values, but when I submit... it doesn't process and redirect to the .msgToUser .... its as if it isn't posting or updating the db.  I'm certain its the new code , it all worked before.  It's an extra or misplaced }

Comment: Actually the top part is working... the bottom is not (tested by changing type between R and C and reloading the page)

Comment: Ok... the issue is that if all the the if / else if are false, I need it to jump out of the nested conditions and process the page... regardless of which condition its under ... the code isn't doing that and thats why the form below isn't posting.  I think I just need 3 seperate if sections and not the connected else if... ill try now